# Qt ugly tabs under OSX

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I have a standard `QTabWidget` and I like the way it looks everywhere, except on MacOSX (see attached image).[image]

Can I change this style? Or maybe use an alternative widget to create tab widgets with similar appearance of, for instance, Safari?

In general, do I have any control of Qt stylings?

Furthermore, all the text is blurred (seems like it is missing antialiasing os something?). What can I do about this?

Thank you!

Comment: What version of Qt and OS X? As for styling, you have plenty. Google for `QTabWidget` and style.

Comment: 1. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html 2. (for qml) http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/scalability.html

Comment: @JonHarper all the latest. Qt 5.6, OS X El Capitan. I googled before (of course), but I think I don't know what I'm looking for, because I can't find anything

Comment: @DmitrySazonov Thank you. That solves the low resolution text

Comment: @DmitrySazonov actually I tried a lot of approaches but still get low resolution in my app. namely, I tried everything here http://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/01/26/high-dpi-support-in-qt-5-6/